# Link error while compiling llvm with a new optimization pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have written a new LLVM optimization pass. I have added this pass by making a new directory at following location:
llvm/lib/Transform/AddSub

I am following the steps as mentioned in the llvm documentation:
http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html

But while compiling I am getting linking errors. May be my build and makefile settings are not correct.

***relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_ZTVN12_GLOBAL__N_18AddSubE' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC***

If I have written an independent llvm pass and added it in a new directory inside llvm at:
llvm/lib/Transform/

what Makefile or build changes do I need to make while writing an independent pass?

Comment: Have you tried building position independent code using `-fPIC`?

Comment: I tried making with -fPIC option but the build fails with same linking error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error when I was trying to follow the Writing An LLVM Pass guide.  For me, the fix was adding a line like this:

char MyPassName::ID = 0;

(I had skipped over that step in the directions.)